# Easy Alternative way of getPixel

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I need an easy way of alternative of `getPixel()` for this code.

And some Explanation. I am new to image manipulation.

I dont want to use getpixel and setpixel.

color tempPix ;

`srcImage` is my Image element.

`x,y,filterx,filtery,s` are variables.

```
int x, y, filterx, filtery;
int s = fmat.Size / 2;
int r, g, b;
Color tempPix; 
tempPix = srcImage.GetPixel(x + filterx - s, y + filtery - s);
```

Here instead of `getPixel` I want to use some other thing, because `getPixel` and `setPixel` are little bit slower.

Comment: And why don't you want to use them? How are we supposed to suggest you an alternative way (given that there's one, I'm not even sure) if we don't know why you don't want to use the standard way?

Comment: Because getpixel and setpixel is slower.So instead of getpixel I want to deirectly assign tempPix.So pls help.......And this code is used for convulation method for image filtering.here is the link which iam using [link]- (michal.is/blog/creating-an-image-processing-library-with-c-part-1/)

Comment: Hey Kookiz,help me man..........

Comment: I don't know of any alternative, GetPixel and SetPixel have been designed for this very purpose.

Comment: If you're only setting one or two pixels or a handful of pixels, then `GetPixel` and `SetPixel` are plenty fast. If you want to manipulate an entire image, you need to work with the image bits directly. For that, you'll want to look into [Bitmap.LockBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx)